# Optimizing filter function in PIG

Tags: java, optimization, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have written a filter function for my pig script but my job is taking too much time. Amount of Data being processed is 15 GB on a 5 node cluster.

Can anybody suggest how to optimize my code:

```
     package org.apache.pig.builtin;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
    import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
    import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
    import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

   public class filterIP extends FilterFunc {
     ArrayList<String> Ar1=new ArrayList<String>(){
    {
add("151.193.220.28");
....
//Around 2000 IP's to be filtered
add("129.22.63.207");
    }
    };
       public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
           if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
               return true;
           try {
               Object values = input.get(0);
               if (values instanceof DataBag)
                   return ((DataBag)values).size() == 0;
               else if (values instanceof Map)
                   return ((Map)values).size() == 0;
           else if (values instanceof String){

            for(String s:Ar1){
            if(((String)values).matches(".*"+s+".*"))
            return false;
            }
            return true;
            //return !((String)values).matches(".*"+Ar1.get(1)+".*");
            }
               else{
            return false;
                  // throw new IOException("Cannot test a " + DataType.findTypeName(values) + " for required match.");
               }
           } catch (ExecException ee) {
               throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", ee);
           }
       }
   }*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashSet rather than an ArrayList - the `for (String s:Ar1)` is your bottleneck.

Are you trying to filter a field by a set of IP addresses?, Can you replace the matches() call with set.contains(values)? This will only work however if your value only contains the IP address, and no pre / post fix characters - but i'm sure you can write a regex to find the ip address string first, extract it and then check for membership against the hash set.

Comment: also instanceof statements are very slow. But actually I think that he should plugin a profiler for that.

Comment: @Chris: I have around 2000 ip-addresses and ip-address class. for e.g 172.87.34.* (just an example) will be a ip address class that I need to match. I can't do it with set.contains function I guess. Since i have to match a lot of keywords, I used matches() function only. Can Hash Set and regular expression matching be integrated in some fashion in this scenario.

Comment: Well if your value contains characters around the IP address then use a regex to find a series of characters that matches the pattern for an IP address, then extract this group and then do the HasSet lookup (you should be able to store 100,000''s if not millions of IP addresses in this HashSet)